# In random loop button dont work properly

Tags: unity, c#, game-loop

I have this code to add 10 point if someone click the button and change the question. But it returns 10 point every time. I want to make it 10,20,30,40... etc.

```
IEnumerator TransitionToNextQuestion() {

            unAnsweredQuestions.Remove(currentQuestion);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (timeBetweenQuestions);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        }

        public void addPoint(int addPoint) {
            point = point + addPoint;
        }

        public void ButtonDown() {
            addPoint (10);
            Debug.Log (point);
            StartCoroutine (TransitionToNextQuestion());

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because **int**s are value types, this means they are located in the stack, which, on the other hand, classes are reference types, so they are located in dynamic memory. In a nutshell: when you have a class, you have its memory's reference, when you have a value type, you have its value, but not its memory reference.

When you pass a value type as a parameter and you modify it inside a function, it will not be modified, you could use a **ref** or **out** modifier in your parameter instead, with that, you also pass the location in memory of that value type. Or you could do a wrapper class.

Example:

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    int integer;

    void Start()
    {
        AddTen(ref integer);
        Debug.Log(integer);  /// Will return 10.
    }

    void AddTen(ref int _value)
    {
        _value += 10;
    }
}
```

So, in short, if you want to modify a value type (structs, string, int, char, double, float, etc.) you should use the **ref** or **out** modifiers.

Check in more depth the **[differences between value and reference types](http://net-informations.com/faq/general/valuetype-referencetype.htm)**.
Hope it helps.